# How to set value dynamically , through there method and properties. c#

Tags: c#

This is the statement I used to set the value :

```
this.codeactivity.output.Value1
```

I am trying to change the numeric value alone to work dynamically.

```
string sValue = "1";
this.codeactivity.output.value+ svalue = "Worked";
```

I have given one more try as below.

```
PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo;
myPropertyInfo = this.CodeActivity.GetType().GetProperties();
this.CodeActivity.Output.

for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(myPropertyInfo[i].ToString());
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong??

Comment: I don't understand. You want to change type of a variable or what? If so, you can use dynamic type.

Comment: the problem is i am unable to do it dynamically. this.codeactivity.Output.Value1 is static string , if i want to add two more values then i have to repeat the same code like this.codeactivity.Output.Value2, this.codeactivity.Output.Value3. i don't want repetitive code. i am looking for something like this  this.Codeactivity.Output.Value"Dynamicvalue". here i forgot to mention , am very new to c#.

Comment: through vb script i know how to change the value dynamic . example below eval("this.CodeActivity.Value"&sNumber& "= "&sValue). dont know how to implement the same in c#

Comment: @MohanP You say you're very new to C#. Perhaps it would be wise to follow some tutorials or read a book about C# first?

Comment: sure i will do as you said. Above mentioned issue i need to close asap.  this is error i am getting 'HP.ST.Ext.BasicActivities.CodeActivity<CodeActivity9Input,CodeActivity9Output>.Output' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @MohanP on what line do you get that error?

Comment: @MohanP Also, what is this "HP.ST.Ext.BasicActivities" you're using? Is there any documentation available for this? (I wasn't able to find it...)

Comment: @PJvG as you said i started learning C#. With the help of reflection concept i have resolved the issue. Thanks guys

Comment: @MohanP Great, good to hear it! Since you've fixed your issue, it would be great if you could either post the answer (solution) here or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question what i raised, here go the answer **

Statement One: this.codeactivity.output.**Value1** here i am tried to change variable name(Value1) dynamically.

This is how i tried to change the value: Eval("this.codeactivity.output.**"&Value1&"**) it will work if i do it in VbScript. But here i am working with object oriented programming C#. Based on the comments to the question i started with C# Reflection concept, then i landed with the solution.

**Solution: **
`string propertyValue = "Mohan"
string propertyName = "Value1"
Type type = this.codeactivity.output.GetType();
 PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName)//Get particular Property;
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType; //get the property type
object propertyVal = Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue , propertyType);//based on type change value.
propertyInfo.SetValue(this.codeactivity.output, propertyVal, null);//Set the value of the property`

Thanks